# Getting the selector, not the handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.close').on('click', '#div1, #div2', function(){
  console.log ( $(this) ); // .close
});
```

If I have multiple elements with close buttons, how do I get the parent element as `this` and not the button?

So if I click the `.close` on `#div1`, I need `#div1` as `this` to work with it.

Comment: `console.log ( $(this) .parent().attr('id'));`

Comment: Walk the DOM tree up.

Comment: Isn't you event delegation in `$('.close').on('click', '#div1, #div2', function(){` the wrong way around? Usually it's like `$('#div1, #div2').on('click', '.close', function(){`, right? And if you do it like that, I think you will have the parent as `this`. I'm probably missing something ...

Comment: @myfunkyside  you are correct. I had mentioned already in my answer too

Comment: Except for my last line, that's not true (couldn't edit it out anymore).

Comment: 3zzy  are you sure the answer you marked is working for you (because i checked above code against your html and it's not working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By instinct, I would look to [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), which takes a selector as a param:

```
var selector = '#div1, #div2';
$('.close').on('click', selector, function(){
    console.log ( $(this).closest(selector) ); // .close
});
```

`.closest` will return a jQuery object representing first node that matches the selector. It starts with the current object and continues to `.parent()` until it finds a match

Comment: this code is not working with OP's HTML. I don't know why he marked it? If you tested it, then please add a working link or snippet  to remove ambiguity (because i checked above code against OP's html and it's not working)

Answer (score 0):

since the element is a child of the element you want to reference, use a parent selector.

```
$(this).parent().hide()
```

Most of the time we would use a class on the element and use closest to select it.

```
$(this).closest('.msg').hide()
```

```js
$('.close').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest(".msg").hide();
});
```

```css
.msg{
   .border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="msg">
    <div class="close">close</div>
    <p>test 1</p>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="msg">
    <div class="close">close</div>
    <p>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need any selector, just a `.closest("div")`.
If you want to be a bit **more specific** like *"The closest ID starts with `div`"* than you could do like:

```js
$('.close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("[id^='div']").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div1">
    <div class="close">close1</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div class="close">close2</div>
</div>
```

Or, by doing it the way you started you could use the `event.delegateTarget` -
 which refers to the actual selector-delegators `$('#div1, #div2')`

```js
$('#div1, #div2').on('click', '.close', function(event) {
    $(event.delegateTarget).fadeOut();
});

// or use also for brevity:
// $("[id^='div']").on(...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div1">
    <div class="close">close1</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div class="close">close2</div>
</div>
```